# Calculating a vector of 0's and 1's with lengths based on observations in another vector

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

Let's say we have a dataframe as such:

```
Length <- floor(runif(25, min = 25, max = 1000))
ObservationID <- c(rep("20200321WT3", 25))
DF <- cbind(ObservationID, Length)
DF <- as.data.frame(DF)
```

I'd like to use the observations in Length to generate a vector consisting of 0's and 1's. This new vector would have a number of 0's equal to the first value in Length, then a number of 1's equal to the second value in Length, then a number of 0's equal to the third value in Length and so on, alternating like that. Or maybe use the observations in Length to create a list of vectors of 0's and 1's and then bind those vectors together into a large vector? Not sure how to do this, and can't seem to find a question like this on stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This base R one-liner can output a vector of alternating zeros and ones repeated `Length` times.

```
unlist(lapply(seq_along(Length), function(i) rep((i - 1)%% 2, each = Length[i])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

```
rep(x = rep_len(x = 0:1,
                length.out = length(x = Length)),
    times = Length)
```